# Принудительное приведение к обобщенному типу T в C#

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с необходимость принудительно привести один тип к другому
`InputData = (TIn) InData`, где в качестве типа для приведения участвует заполнитель обобщенного типа `TIn`

```
public class SerialPortExhangeBehavior<TIn>
{
    public TIn InData { get; set; }

    private async Task ExchangeService(MasterSerialPort port, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        //принудительно приведение к типу TIn
        var writeProvider = new PanelMg6587WriteDataProvider() {InputData = (TIn)InData};
    }
}

class PanelMg6587WriteDataProvider : IExchangeDataProvider<UniversalInputType, Mg6587Output>
{
   public UniversalInputType InputData { get; set; }
   public Mg6587Output OutputData { get; }
}
```

При создании `SerialPortExhangeBehavior` я закрываю типом `UniversalInputType`

```
var SpExhBehavior = new SerialPortExhangeBehavior<UniversalInputType>();
```

И я бы хотел принудительно преобразовывать `InputData = (TIn)InData`.
Пусть даже возникнет исключение если типы не приводимы.

прошу помочь!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно универсальное приведение «силой», делайте через `object`:

```
 InputData = (UniversalInputType)(object)InData;
```

Но есть хороший шанс, что вам это не нужно в реальности, а можно обойтись констрейнтом на обобщённый тип:

```
public class SerialPortExhangeBehavior<TIn> where TIn : UniversalInputType
{
    ...
```

При этом тип, не приводимый к `UniversalInputType`, просто не скомпилируется.

Comment: через (object) не работает. А вот насчет кривой архитектуры вы возможно правы. И чем мне делать where TIn : UniversalInputType проще вообще не использовать обобщения а сразу UniversalInputType .

Comment: @Aldmi: Хм, а почему через `object` не работает? Что выдаёт? У меня вроде компилируется.

Comment: Извиняюсь! Поздно ваш вопрос заметил, я уже исправил код, но VS подчеркивала такое приведение.